# Regarding Docusign envelope API

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the below response using `Docusign` envelope API

```
{ 
  ""envelopeId"": ""0aac02c3-ccdc-4bfe-88af-eefa2438d696"", 
  ""uri"": ""/envelopes/0aac02c3-ccdc-4bfe-88af-eefa2438d696"",
  ""statusDateTime"": ""2016-10-14T10:39:02.4900000Z"", 
  ""status"": ""created""
}
```

I am unable to open the envelope, even though I have logged into the `Docusign` site in the web. Let me know the URL to open the envelope. The response doesn't give the exact URL.

Comment: Is this remote signing or embedded signing? In other words, did you expect DocuSign to send out an email to the recipient notifying them they need to sign ?

Answer (score 0):

Created status means you will find it in your draft folder and that it has not been sent. If you want a [POST sender view](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm) then you will need to make the correct call and use the URL returned by DocuSign to access the view and send the envelope.